# A customer is someone who 'buys' but what is he if there's no purchase made?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

The noun *customer* is clear to all of us.

> [customer](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/customer) - *a person or an organization that ***buys*** something from a shop/store or business* - OALD 
>   [customer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/customer) - *someone who ***buys*** goods or services from a business.* -MW 
>  [customer](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/customer?showCookiePolicy=true) - *a person who ***buys*** - Collins

And there are many more dictionaries. Note that I'm talking about **the first meaning** and not the other which is referred to *dealing* as in *A cool customer.*

**Now the context**

The Bishop mall has a large number of footfalls everyday. However, not all of them *buy*. Many simply enquire about the product and go away. I could use the word 'footfall' because I'm referring to the masses. But I'm talking about one person and *'he's a footfall, not a customer'* does not look correct.

My question is, what are they called? They ***did not buy*** anything. Are they merely referred to *enthusiasts?*

In my day-to-day language, any person who enters into the shop is a ***customer***. As being a manager, I'd ask my salesperson, *"Go, attend the customer!"*

This question is *not* nitpicking, but there has been an actual situation like this. While discussing our friend's shop's business, I got stuck while describing that person 'X' is not a customer (won't buy anything) he's just **__________**.

[I know the word '[window-shopper](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/window-shopping)' but it won't fit here. The person is not staring at store's windows but he actually ***enters,*** enquires, *might* show some interest and then go away!]

***Visitors*** is another word that I thought of but it's very casual. It does not fulfill the qualities of customer of *being enthusiastic, curious or throwing some enquiry.*

Is there any term for a person who does not buy anything?

Comment: We sell gym memberships where I work, and the industry standard is to call non-members who might become members `prospects`. As in `prospective member/customer`

Comment: Anyone who looks at your products is a potential customer and is therefore a 'prospect' or a 'potential customer/client'. In the context of a shop or website they can be said to be 'browsing', 'taking a look', 'window shopping' or any of a selection of idiomatic phrases. As for someone who doesn't buy anything you might use the phrase 'missed opportunity' - there is always the potential to sell something to someone if you are serious about your business so it's all about maximising the opportunities to buy for any potential customers. (I don't have enough rep to answer this hence the comment)

Comment: Window Shopper isn't someone that looks at a window, it is someone that goes into stores and just looks around.  It's not a literal term

Comment: Who is listening to this description? If you call "prospective buyers" or "visitors" something as cold as "prospects" or "opportunities" they'll likely walk away because they want to be seen as more than just a wallet to be plundered. If the audience is supervisors & business managers, then "potential customers/buyers" is ok. To employees, everybody should be a "customer" whether or not  they buy something to avoid negative reviews about the service. An informal/dismissive term is "looky-loo." A neutral option is to say they're "just browsing/looking." Depends who you're talking to.

Comment: "The noun customer is clear to all of us" -- not always in practical usage. In a large store, if a voice comes over the PA saying, "customer announcement", or "we request that customers...", it doesn't mean that the announcement doesn't apply to people who aren't buying anything. The dictionary can state that this is incorrect usage if it likes, but it's common and intelligible to native speakers, and wouldn't normally be questioned. So by all means decline to use "customers" yourself to include non-purchasers, but sometimes you must understand "customers" to include them.

Comment: good point @mc01: good point to mention that you probably  SHOULD NOT ADDRESS anyone with `prospect`. However it probably would be equally rude to call them `customer`, and when necessary you'd stick either to `sir` or `mam`, or ask for their name.

Comment: I don't see how you could tell that some random person in your store is ***not a customer***. Perhaps you recognize them as having recently visited the store without making a purchase, but I don't see how you could say they have ***never*** purchased anything in your store. Are you always present when the store is open? They might have purchased something while you were not there, or while you were there but were too busy to notice, or from another location of your store. Plus referring to them as ***not a customer***, infers that they be treated differently than a ***customer***.

Comment: Potential-customer???

Comment: What are "**footfalls**"? Is this an Indian English expression? I've never heard of it. I'm amazed nobody has picked up on this. I would also capitalize *mall* in  *Bishop Mall*, because *mall*  is part of a proper noun. "Dolphin Mall" is the name of a mall in Miami, "St Stephen's Green" is the name of a public [green](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/green?s=t) (n. green=a land covered with grass) in Dublin;  "Regents Park" is the name of a park in London.

Comment: @Mari-LouA footfalls is Indian English. Maybe, derived from [BrE](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/footfall). I have been in marketing for some years and here, the word is too common. You *may* call it as a business term.

Comment: Good to know! I had never heard of that expression before. I would have said **foot steps** in the example given by the dictionary. Thank you for replying so quickly, today I've learnt a new word.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You are welcome. We spend a lot of efforts in turning *footfalls* into genuine buyers. That's what the marketing is all about. Whenever guys used to submit me a report, I always asked for the ratio of buyers:footfalls. Haha...then that was a trap for them. ;)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Footfalls is not Indian English, although Indians and others may use it. The OED says "British English originally".

Comment: @BillyKerr I know... it was in a recent question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/329942/what-does-football-mean-in-this-sentence-we-are-seeing-more-football-here-w/329943#329943

Comment: Only I had completely forgotten the word, eight years later. I think it's stuck with me now :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In agreement with [talrnu](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/8718/talrnu)’s [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/a-customer-is-someone-who-buys-but-what-is-he-if-theres-no-purchase-made#comment-58202), I think **“window shopper”** is in fact appropriate here. In usage (which might be better represented on Urban Dictionary and Yahoo Answers), this term is commonly employed to refer to people who walk around both inside and outside of shops, and is used to differentiate such people from those who have more of an inclination to make a purchase.

From Urban Dictionary:

1. > Someone who looks at stuff they can’t buy.
2. > When one visits a store or mall to admire goods rather than to purchase them.

From Yahoo Answers:

> It implies [. . .] someone who is not serious (a shopper who has no real intention of buying [. . .])

---

**“Browser”** does not sound right to my ear as it seems like an awkward nounification. Most people will think of something they use to view websites. I have not heard the word used this way. It would probably require explanation, which would defeat the purpose of having a single word for it.

That said, I *have* heard people say that they are **“just browsing”** to indicate that they are not actively pursuing a purchase at that moment. For your case, I could certainly see someone saying “he’s just browsing.” As far as saying “he’s not a customer”, you have another problem.

---

**Anyone visiting the store is, potentially speaking, a customer.** so it’s not ideal to say “he’s not a customer” unless you are pointing to an employee, security guard, pomeranian, etc. You might be clearer if you qualify the word “customer” before you establish this comparison, for example: “he’s not a *serious* customer, he’s _____________.”

---

Lastly, another term I know for such a person is to describe them as a **looky-loo.**

> ### looky-loo
>
> (also **lookie-loo**)
> NOUN
>   
> <sup>*INFORMAL*</sup>
>
> 1.1 A person who seems interested in making a purchase, but whose actual intention is only to browse:
>
> *a treat for all the North Shore’s looky-loos: the popular Spring Designer Kitchen Tour*
>
> *A good business broker will separate the real buyers from the looky-loos, bring in more qualified prospects, and usually can garner a better price for the business.*
>
> <sub>Source: [Definition of looky-loo in Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/looky-loo)</sub>

Comment: I had actually upvoted your answer and was giving some additional opinion (namely that I thought the meaning of "shopper" merited inclusion in what I otherwise considered a good answer). Sorry you thought my comments off topic and unrelated.

Comment: Accepted for the looky-loo. fits exactly what I mean. They portray that they are customers but finally walk off with no purchase.

Comment: +1 & spot-on. I'm at a loss as to why so many dictionary definitions include the word _windows_ in their definitions, when the term is more widely applied than that.

Comment: @J.R. I'd assume it's because of the etymology and history, and because established idioms and meanings are extremely difficult to expunge from a language (e.g. SE's inbox icon is literally a picture of a box which used to sit on desks, for receiving incoming mail). Remember that windows used to be rare and expensive. "Window shopping" originated as a way of advertising; big windows made it easy to take a peek at the wares, without wasting the shopkeeper's time or getting turned away for not buying. Informative: http://www2.iath.virginia.edu/mhc/Archive/On-line-pubs/2001/paper4.html

Answer (score 21):

Be careful with your

> person 'X' is not a customer (won't buy anything) he's just (Y)

statement. Even window shoppers are **potential customers**, which is the word I would use. Just because someone has not purchased something does not mean that they won't and treating them as such is usually enough to turn a potential customer away.

Comment: That's not what I mean. It may happen that they never come back. They are just visitors, footfall or the like. Prospects and potential're almost same if you consider. Every person ***can*** be converted into customer and here, I'm *not* considering them potential at all. They're just visitors, window shoppers/enthusiastic about product. I already mentioned this. Every customer is a potential customer and thus every person who comes in the shop is a potential customer. But this is good term for the 'sales training manual' not here. But no downvote as this is due to misunderstanding.

Comment: @MaulikV In that case, just call them window shoppers. The term is not so literal that the customer has to actually be looking through a window in order to qualify.

Comment: I see. If it's not that literal, it can be a good choice

Answer (score 18):

*Window-shopper* doesn't fit, but *shopper* does. They are merely visiting shops, not necessarily buying (at least, not in a specified shop).

Comment: http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/shopper

Comment: Many times I've heard *window shopper* when referring to a shopper who doesn't buy anything, regardless of the involvement of windows (i.e. it even sounds right when the shopper visits a store that doesn't have windows). Still, when I think of a mall like the one in the question's given context, I think of all of the people visiting it as *shoppers* without knowing anything about whether or not they've purchased anything.

Comment: Also, consider announcements made on department store intercoms: they often begin with "Attention shoppers...", addressing people in the store who still haven't bought anything yet.

Comment: Shopper: One who visits stores in search of merchandise or bargains.--thefreedictionary.com. Shoppers become customers when they make a purchase.

Comment: @MaulikV - Try http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/shopper. Pay particular attention to the words "***or look at***" in that definition. (Never make the mistake of assuming one dictionary's definition restricts a word's meaning unless you've consulted SEVERAL other dictionaries).

Comment: @J.R. It's answerer's job to provide the reference to avoid such ambiguity. I generally refer to OALD which is believed to be standard. And if you see my question, while raising my point, I referred several dictionaries!

Comment: @MaulikV - Your first comment makes it look like you are disagreeing with the answerer here. I've provided a second definition which shows the definition you've provided is not a universal definition. As for your other comment to me, OALD is **not** "standard" – it's merely one decent dictionary among several worthy of examination. (I hope you are not confusing OALD with the OED, just because they have the word "Oxford".)

Answer (score 13):

That person is not a customer, he's just a **browser**

[browser](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/browser): a person or thing that browses.
[browse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/browse): to look leisurely at goods displayed for sale, as in a store.

Comment: +1 for the word *leisurely* this is quite close to the picture I have in my mind. :) Thanks

Comment: Not to be confused with *Bowser*, an evil character from Mario video games. Be sure not to give the impression that your shoppers are evil for not buying things :-)

Comment: Or browser that we are viewing this site from.

Comment: +1 if you are talking about the potential customer where you can be overheard by other customers, use _customer_.  If you are in a staff meeting or writing a training manual, non-buyers are people who browse.

Answer (score 13):

They are called 'prospects'.

Potential customer is a description not a term. A 'prospect' is short for "a prospective buyer" - someone who may buy (from you) if you (the salesperson) induces him/her sufficiently.

I use this term commonly. And it is also common in various sales & marketing books and manuals.

Comment: It seems to me that the OP is attempting to describe people who are basically not worth inducing in any way because they have no intention of making a purchase.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Exactly and is quite common in India. As we have paid audience, these are opposite to them. They just kill the time by entering, inquiring, showing fake interest and finally walking off

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend the word patron. This is someone who visits an establishment, and may or not pay for a service at that time, but still visits the location. It still applies to people who do make purchases, but keep in mind this is considered a polite term.
I suggested this mainly because in a lot of stores I visit, there is some message such as "Thank You For Your Patronage!".

Comment: A patron provides support to an establishment. If you enter a store and leave without purchasing anything, you're providing no support whatsoever to that store.

Comment: +1 for Patron.  Even if you enter/leave without purchasing anything, you may provide support for the store via word of mouth, you may be considering a purchase at a later date, or the store may benefit from your presence (if you are a celebrity, or simply from the appearance of being crowded/busy/cool).

Comment: Definitions for “patron” say things like “a person who gives financial [. . .] support to a[n. . .] organization” and “a customer [. . .] of a store”. If anything, this word could be contrasted with “customer” in the opposite direction, such as “many customers enter the shop, but only a few patronize our establishment”.

Comment: Those who make use of charities, where service or support is given without any fee being required, are also referred to as patrons.

Comment: I don't think the classical definition of an Artists Patron is the same as the general commerce related meaning. If I were to enter a restaurant, have a glass of water while looking over the menu and then decide I'll eat elsewhere, i'm still a patron. Or a guest, in this sense the terms are fairly equivalent. I think patron fits establishments with a minimum of hospitality services. Otherwise, I would go with patron.

Comment: If you didn’t buy anything, those signs are not thanking you.

Answer (score 4):

Several of the other words are good options, but if you want a word that in the general sense describes people who have entered the mall, but haven't yet purchased anything the word you're looking for is:

**Visitor**

"There were thirteen **visitors** to the shop this morning, but only two bought anything."

Comment: If I don't get any specific word what I'm looking for, I'd ***certainly*** used this word. And, I already mentioned this in my question. The only thing that prevents me to go agree fully is *visitors* not necessarily have the characters of customers.

Comment: Visitors are people who "visit" places, which can include countries, towns, seaside resorts, museums, galleries, castles etc. You can also have visitors who *visit* patients in hospitals. But people who **go** into supermarkets, bars, cafès, cinemas, restaurants, shopping malls/centres are NOT visitors.

Comment: @mari-lou surely someone who goes into a shopping mall is visiting it, and so can be considered by the shopping mall to be a person on a visit to that mall?

Comment: This about it by analogy to domestic houses. "We had three visitors over at my parents house whilst I was staying" is basically the same form as "We had 3 visitors to the shopping centre whilst I was on shift".

Comment: You can them whatever you like, but normally people who go into a supermarket, coffee shop, boutique etc. have as their main purpose to purchase something, therefore shoppers, or customers is the most appropriate term. [Visitors](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/visitor) on the other hand have as their main purpose to *see* someone (a friend, a relative, someone sick) or view (sightsee) a town, a city etc.

Answer (score 1):

True, the dictionaries do equate customer with someone who buys something. But, while I think that they believe what they've said is what they mean, what they actually mean may not be what they said.

Sorry, couldn't resist that.

From the perspective of the mall of course, everyone who visits (other than those working there) are customers - 'buying' does not necessarily mean parting with cold hard cash. They have 'brought' the concept of visiting the mall.

I hope that we can all agree that a broader definition would include the user of services that are provided - the display provision of goods for sale is a service; if you consume that service then you are a customer.

The [American Marketing Association](https://www.ama.org/resources/Pages/Dictionary.aspx?dLetter=C) takes it further, their definition runs:

*The actual or prospective purchaser of products or services.*

Or, from the [Marketing Association of Australia and New Zealand](http://www.marketing.org.au/default.aspx?i=o7/3rRJaaY0=&t=jZS6ngCVPug=) (my bold):

*Any recipient of a product (goods and services); **anyone who is affected by what one produces**. A customer can be external or outside the organisation or they can be internal to the organisation.  Person or organisation actually making the purchasing decision not necessarily the 'consumer' or 'user'. The receiver of an output of a process, either internal or external to the organisation. Can be a person, department, company, etc.*

Still not convinced? Back to the OED then:

1592   R. Greene *Thirde Pt. Conny-catching* sig. E3,   **His shop very well frequented with Customers.**
1725   D. Defoe *Compl. Eng. Tradesman I*. viii. 102   **Parcels fit to fill their shops, and invite their customers.**

Each of those examples seem to fit the case that is being discussed here

Answer (score 0):

> The mall has a large number of footfalls everyday. However, not all of them buy.

What is their intention? If I go to a mall/store with the intention of buying something I consider myself a customer. Maybe I don't buy anything today - I like that $1000 digital camera but I have to talk to the credit card first.

If I go with Wifey for the purpose of carrying the bags **I** am not a customer<sup>1</sup>. If I am there to help make a decision then I am. If Wifey is late and I have an hour to kill I will consider myself a browser (or window shopper) in the tool aisle.

1. Note to managers everywhere: Get some benches. Less complaining from the bag-carriers and thus more sales from the real customer.

Comment: I disagree. Question asks what to call people in a store who do not buy. If I am in a store with the _intention_ of buying, I consider myself a customer wether I actually buy something or not.

Comment: Paul: I agree with your comment – and your answer. I'd like to think of myself a customer when I walk in the door, not when I whip out my credit card.

Comment: Just as importantly, if you treat them like they aren’t customers, they won’t be.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes *potential customer*, but the reason I feel *customer* is valid is there is an ongoing relationship. They will come back again some other time and buy something. Or rather, their relation to you is one where they buy and you sell. Even if they don't buy, their ability to do so is their defining quality when you talk about them.

In a business context the term *client* is often preferred. This would be incorrect in the case of a store, though (if you said "client" to refer to someone shopping for shoes, I would assume you're about to buy 300 shoes wholesale and sell to someone else, for instance). It's slightly synonymous but it's understood you try to serve a client before you know whether they will buy, whereas, to me, customer does have the implication that they are much closer to making a purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Both etymologically and de facto, customers are customers whether or not they buy; shop personnel habitually refer to all members of the public who enter the store as *customer*.

Asked if you need any help, you might say:

*No thanks, I am just browsing.*

or

*I'm just having a look round, thanks.*

But I for one would never say

*I'm just window shopping.*

when I am already inside the store (perhaps a profusion of glass displays inside the store might tempt me to say this). This is not quite the same as them (later on, amongst themselves) referring to me, a non-purchasing customer, as a window shopper.