# What does "football" mean in this sentence: "We are seeing more football here. We are seeing more clients."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, proverbs

The following sentence is from a British TV channel about Britain debt problem.

[Broke: Britain's Debt Emergency | Dispatches | Channel 4 Documentaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9UlLGAywqU&t=4m16s)  (see 4:16-4:21):

> **"We are seeing more football here.** We are seeing more clients."

I checked online what does "to see more football" mean, but found no entry for that.

What does **"football"** mean here?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and mention that the video in question isn't a sports documentary, but about "Britain's Debt Emergency". The speaker of the phrase "We're seeing more football here" is talking about an increase of clients for a debt advise service. So we're probably not talking about sports, but in some figurative sense. If I had to guess, I'd read it as something like "we're seeing more action here", but this is complete guesswork.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck - 'football' is a mis-hearing. It's 'footfall'.

Comment: While 'football' is a mis-hearing, please do not edit the question just to correct it. It changes the intent of the question, as the OP was confused about (and did research on) 'football', not necessarily about the meaning of 'footfall'.  It also renders the current accepted answer nonsensical, as it includes information correcting the mishearing. -- If you feel the need to edit the question title, be sure to keep the concept of the mishearing intact.

Comment: @R.M. Agreed, and since this is a highly viewed video, a lot of non-native (and even native, myself included) English speakers will watch it and wonder what it means to see more football and find this Q&A.

Comment: I am so annoyed about the airbrush-edit that I would delete my answer if I could. Don't need this type of behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've raised a flag and asked the mods to lock the question. It's plain silly "correcting" a misspelling or a misheard word. Even I thought the speaker had said football because I had never heard of *footfall* before in my life. I don't think I'm alone... but even if I were,  the word "football" is the quintessential element of the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - the title is edited back, but not the question.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Edit done, it completely escaped my attention. I find it unbelievable that the question attracted 4 downvotes too, what is wrong with people? The question named its source, it has a link, it is interesting, and the answer is very useful.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

She doesn't say 'football'. She says

> we are seeing more **footfall**, we're seeing more clients

'Footfall' is a term used in retail and other customer-facing business contexts and means 'number of visitors'. This lady is a (probably volunteer) debt adviser. She works at a branch of the Citizens Advice Bureau (CAB), an independent organisation specialising in confidential information and advice to assist people with legal, debt, consumer, housing and other problems in the United Kingdom. People can contact the CAB by email or phone, or visit in person. All CABs offer consultations by appointment; some also offer a 'drop-in' service as well.

> footfall noun (BUSINESS) [ U ]
> specialized UK (US foot traffic)
>
> the number of people who go into a shop or business in a particular
> period of time

Comment: I wouldn't have known what *footfall* meant without using a dictionary. But is her saying  "seeing more clients" a redundancy, a way to clarify the meaning? Or is she making a distinguishment between visitors and actual clients?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - a redundancy, I think. Maybe she is used to talking about footfall in a work-planning context, and she used that word and then decided to clarify for more general listeners. It is a term that UK people will come across in discussions about shopping, transport{ation], etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I mean, if you expect 100 visitors a day you can make certain decisions about premises and staffing, but you would make different ones if you expected 500.

Comment: Ack, I should have said **distinction** instead of *distinguishment* I thought it looked odd but the right word didn't come to mind. Far, far too late to edit now. Humbug.

Comment: @Mari-LouA distinguishment in British English NOUN obsolete the quality or condition of being distinguished. (Cambridge) You're good. Webster likes it too. There's no such word as 'obsolete' in my personal, mental dictionary.

Comment: Footfall is a little different to clients because it depends on how often each turns up. Footfall is the number of people passing a given point in a given time and only includes physical bodies (not remote, phone-calls, email, etc). It's a term to help you work out how many toilets or car park spaces you need, how big the door needs to be, how many people you need at reception, how many tables in a coffee shop, etc. I don't think she was making this subtle distinction though: I think she was mainly repeating for emphasis, clarity, etc.

Comment: @DanSheppard footfall is not well defined enough to distinguish between number of people visiting versus number of unique people visiting, i.e. it may vary between times it’s used